# Call a Server-side Method on a Resource in a RESTful Way

Tags: rest, url, api-design

Keep in mind I have a rudimentary understanding of REST. Let's say I have this URL:

```
http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/
```

And now, I want to make the server make the dog bark. Only the server knows how to do this. Let's say I want to have it run on a CRON job that makes the dog bark every 10 minutes for the rest of eternity. What does that call look like? I kind of want to do this:

URL request:

```
ACTION http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/
```

In the request body:

```
{"action":"bark"}
```

Before you get mad at me for making up my own HTTP method, help me out and give me a better idea on how I should invoke a server-side method in a RESTful way. :)

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

Some more clarification around what the "bark" method does. Here are some options that may result in differently structured API calls:

1. bark just sends an email to dog.email and records nothing.
2. bark sends an email to dog.email and the increments dog.barkCount by 1.
3. bark creates a new "bark" record with bark.timestamp recording when the bark occured. It also increments dog.barkCount by 1.
4. bark runs a system command to pull the latest version of the dog code down from Github. It then sends a text message to dog.owner telling them that the new dog code is in production.

Comment: Interestingly, adding a bounty appears to have attracted worse answers than you originally had ;-)

 When evaluating answers remember that: 

1) The specs for the HTTP verbs preclude any choice other than POST. 

2) REST has nothing to do with URL structure – it is a generic list of contraints (stateless, cacheable, layered, uniform interface, etc) than confer benefits (scalability, reliability, visibility, etc).

3) Current practice (such as using POST in RPC specs) trumps definitionalists who are making-up their own API rules. 4) REST requires a uniform interface (following the HTTP spec).

Comment: @Kirk what are your thoughts on the new answers? Is there anything you still want to know but wasn't addressed in any of them? I'd be more than happy to edit my answer again if it can be more helpful.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger `PATCH` can be appropriate. I explain why toward the end of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17016682/972499).

Comment: PATCH would only be appropriate for incrementing the *dog.barkCount* by one.  POST is the method for sending email, creating a new bark record, running commands to download from Github, or triggering a text message.   @Jordan, your reading of the PATCH RFC is imaginative but somewhat at odds with its intent as a variant of PUT for partial resource modification.  I don't think you're helping the OP by coming up with unconventional readings of the HTTP specs rather than acknowledging the standard practice of using POST for remote procedure calls.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger whose practice _de facto_ standardizes POST? All standard RPC interfaces I've seen identify a resource by entity (not RESTful), vs URI, so a valid answer prioritizing RPC convention would need to be unconventional anyway, which I think disproves the value of conventional RPC: one is imaginative or inconsistent. You can never go _wrong_ with POST as it is the catch-all for data processing, but there are more specific methods. REST means naming resources and describing changes in their state, not naming state-changing procedures. PATCH and POST both describe state changes.

Comment: Whatever you use from other answers but never use GET for such case, because in many clients like browser GET is cacheable, and chances of many side-effects, POST, PUT, etc are ok from other answers

Answer (score 311, accepted):

### Why aim for a RESTful design?

The RESTful principles **bring the features that make web sites easy** (for a *random human user* to "surf" them) **to the web services API design**, so they are easy for a programmer to use. [REST isn't good because it's REST, it's good because it's good.](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2009/03/20/Rest-Casuistry) And it is good mostly because it is **simple**.

The simplicity of plain HTTP (without SOAP envelopes and single-URI overloaded `POST` services), what **some may call *"lack of features"***, is actually **its greatest strength**. Right off the bat, HTTP asks you to have *addressability* and *statelessness*: the two basic design decisions that keep HTTP scalable up to today's mega-sites (and mega-services).

But REST is not the silver bulltet: **Sometimes an RPC-style** ("Remote Procedure Call" - such as SOAP) **may be appropriate**, and sometimes other needs take precedence over the virtues of the Web. This is fine. What we don't really like **is needless complexity**. Too often a programmer or a company brings in RPC-style Services for a job that plain old HTTP could handle just fine. The effect is that HTTP is reduced to a transport protocol for an enormous XML payload that explains what's "really" going on (not the URI or the HTTP method give a clue about it). The resulting service is far too complex, impossible to debug, and won't work unless your clients have the **exact setup** as the developer intended.

Same way a Java/C# code can be *not* object-oriented, just using HTTP does not make a design RESTful. One may be caught up in the rush of **thinking** about their services **in terms of actions and remote methods** that should be called. No wonder this will mostly end up in a RPC-Style service (or a REST-RPC-hybrid). The first step is to think differently. A RESTful design can be achieved in many ways, one way is to **think of your application in terms of resources, not actions:**

> Instead of thinking in terms of actions it can perform ("do a search for places on the map")...
>
> ...try to think in terms of the **results** of those actions ("the list of places on the map matching a search criteria").

I'll go for examples below.
(Other key aspect of REST is the use of HATEOAS - I don't brush it here, but I talk about it quickly [at another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30607633/1850609).)

### Issues of the first design

Let's take a look a the proposed design:

```
ACTION http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/
```

First off, we should not consider creating a **new HTTP verb** (`ACTION`). Generally speaking, this is *undesirable* for several reasons:

- **(1)** Given only the service URI, how will a "random" programmer know the `ACTION` verb exists?
- **(2)** if the programmer knows it exists, how will he know its semantics? What does that verb mean?
- **(3)** what properties (safety, idempotence) should one expect that verb to have?
- **(4)** what if the programmer has a very simple client that only handles standard HTTP verbs?
- **(5)** ...

Now let's **consider using `POST`** (I'll discuss why below, just take my word for it now):

```
POST /v1/dogs/1/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.animals.com

{"action":"bark"}
```

This *could* be OK... but **only if**:

- `{"action":"bark"}` was a document; and
- `/v1/dogs/1/` was a "document processor" (factory-like) URI. <sub>A "document processor" is a URI that you'd just "throw things at" and "forget" about them - the processor may redirect you to a newly created resource after the "throwing". E.g. the URI for posting messages at a message broker service, which, after the posting would redirect you to a URI that shows the status of the message's processing.</sub>

I don't know much about your system, but I'd already bet both aren't true:

- `{"action":"bark"}` **is not a document**, it actually **is the method** you are trying to *ninja-sneak* into the service; and
- the `/v1/dogs/1/` URI represents a "dog" resource (probably the dog with `id==1`) and not a document processor.

So all we know now is that the design above is not so RESTful, but what is that exactly? **What is so bad about it?** Basically, it is bad because that is complex URI with complex meanings. You can't infer anything from it. How would a programmer know a dog have a `bark` action that can be secretly infused with a `POST` into it?

### Designing your question's API calls

So let's cut to the chase and try to design those barks RESTfully by thinking **in terms of resources**. Allow me to quote the [Restful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260) book:

> A `POST` request is an attempt to create a new resource from an existing
> one. The existing resource may be the parent of the new one in a
> data-structure sense, the way the root of a tree is the parent of all
> its leaf nodes. Or the existing resource may be a special *"factory"*
> resource whose only purpose is to generate other resources. The
> representation sent along with a `POST` request describes the initial
> state of the new resource. As with PUT, a `POST` request doesn’t need to
> include a representation at all.

Following the description above we can see that **`bark`** can be modeled as **a subresource of a `dog`** (since a `bark` is contained within a dog, that is, a bark is "barked" **by** a dog).

From that reasoning we already got:

- The method is `POST`
- The resource is `/barks`, subresource of dog: `/v1/dogs/1/barks`, representing a `bark` "factory". That URI is unique for each dog (since it is under `/v1/dogs/{id}`).

Now each case of your list has a specific behavior.

##1. bark just sends an e-mail to `dog.email` and records nothing.

Firstly, is barking (sending an e-mail) a synchronous or an asynchronous task? Secondly does the `bark` request require any document (the e-mail, maybe) or is it empty?

#### 1.1 bark sends an e-mail to `dog.email` and records nothing (as a synchronous task)

This case is simple. A call to the `barks` factory resource yields a bark (an e-mail sent) right away and the response (if OK or not) is given right away:

```
POST /v1/dogs/1/barks HTTP/1.1
Host: api.animals.com
Authorization: Basic mAUhhuE08u724bh249a2xaP=

(entity-body is empty - or, if you require a **document**, place it here)

200 OK
```

As it records (changes) nothing, `200 OK` is enough. It shows that everything went as expected.

#### 1.2 bark sends an e-mail to `dog.email` and records nothing (as an asynchronous task)

In this case, the client must have a way to track the `bark` task. The `bark` task then should be a resource with its own URI.:

```
POST /v1/dogs/1/barks HTTP/1.1
Host: api.animals.com
Authorization: Basic mAUhhuE08u724bh249a2xaP=

{document body, if needed;
NOTE: when possible, the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink
to the newly created resource (bark) URI, the same returned in the Location header
(also notice that, for the 202 status code, the Location header meaning is not
standardized, thus the importance of a hipertext/hyperlink response)}

202 Accepted
Location: http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/barks/a65h44
```

This way, each `bark` is traceable. The client can then issue a `GET` to the `bark` URI to know it's current state. Maybe even use a `DELETE` to cancel it.

### 2. bark sends an e-mail to `dog.email` and then increments `dog.barkCount` by 1

This one can be trickier, if you want to let the client know the `dog` resource gets changed:

```
POST /v1/dogs/1/barks HTTP/1.1
Host: api.animals.com
Authorization: Basic mAUhhuE08u724bh249a2xaP=

{document body, if needed; when possible, containing a hipertext/hyperlink with the address
in the Location header -- says the standard}

303 See Other
Location: http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1
```

In this case, the `location` header's intent is to let the client know he should take a look at `dog`. From the [HTTP RFC about `303`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.4):

> This method    exists primarily to allow the output of a
> **`POST`-activated script** to    redirect the user agent to a selected resource.

If the task is asynchronous, a `bark` subresource is needed just like the `1.2` situation and the `303` should be returned at a `GET .../barks/Y` when the task is complete.

### 3. bark creates a new "`bark`" record with `bark.timestamp` recording when the bark occured. It also increments `dog.barkCount` by 1.

```
POST /v1/dogs/1/barks HTTP/1.1
Host: api.animals.com
Authorization: Basic mAUhhuE08u724bh249a2xaP=

(document body, if needed)

201 Created
Location: http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/barks/a65h44
```

In here, the `bark` is a created due to the request, so the status `201 Created` is applied.

If the creation is asynchronous, a `202 Accepted` is required ([as the HTTP RFC says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.2)) instead.

The timestamp saved is a part of `bark` resource and can be retrieved with a `GET` to it. The updated dog can be "documented" in that `GET dogs/X/barks/Y` as well.

### 4. bark runs a system command to pull the latest version of the dog code down from Github. It then sends a text message to `dog.owner` telling them that the new dog code is in production.

The wording of this one is complicated, but it pretty much is a simple asynchronous task:

```
POST /v1/dogs/1/barks HTTP/1.1
Host: api.animals.com
Authorization: Basic mAUhhuE08u724bh249a2xaP=

(document body, if needed)

202 Accepted
Location: http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/barks/a65h44
```

The client then would issue `GET`s to `/v1/dogs/1/barks/a65h44` to know the current state (if the code was pulled, it the e-mail was sent to the owner and such). Whenever the dog changes, a `303` is appliable.

### Wrapping up

Quoting [Roy Fielding](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post):

> The only thing REST requires of methods is that they be uniformly
> defined for all resources (i.e., so that intermediaries don’t have to
> know the resource type in order to understand the meaning of the
> request).

In the above examples, `POST` is uniformly designed. It will make the dog "`bark`". That is not safe (meaning bark has effects on the resources), nor idempotent (each request yields a new `bark`), which fits the `POST` verb well.

A programmer would know: a `POST` to `barks` yields a `bark`. The response status codes (also with entity-body and headers when necessary) do the job of explaining what changed and how the client can and should proceed.

<sub>Note: The primary sources used were: "[Restful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260)" book, the [HTTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and [Roy Fielding's blog](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled).</sub>

---

**Edit:**

The question and thus the answer have changed quite a bit since they were first created. The **original question** asked about the design of a URI like:

```
ACTION http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/?action=bark
```

Below is the explanation of why it is not a good choice:

How clients tell the server **WHAT TO DO** with the data is the *method information*.

- RESTful web services convey method information in the HTTP method.
- Typical RPC-Style and SOAP services keep theirs in the entity-body and HTTP header.

**WHICH PART** of the data [the client wants the server] to operate on is the *scoping information*.

- RESTful services use the URI. SOAP/RPC-Style services once again use the entity-body and HTTP headers.

As an example, take Google's URI `http://www.google.com/search?q=DOG`. There, the method information is `GET` and the scoping information is `/search?q=DOG`.

Long story short:

- In **RESTful architectures**, the method information goes into the HTTP method.
- In **Resource-Oriented Architectures**, the scoping information goes into the URI.

And the rule of thumb:

> If the HTTP method doesn’t match the method information, the service isn’t RESTful. If the scoping information isn’t in the URI, the service isn’t resource-oriented.

You can put the *"bark"*  *"action"* in the URL (or in the entity-body) and use `POST`. No problem there, it works, and may be the simplest way to do it, **but this isn't RESTful**.

To keep your service really RESTful, you may have to take a step back and think about what you really want to do here (what effects will it have on the resources).

I can't talk about your specific business needs, but let me give you an example: Consider a RESTful ordering service where orders are at URIs like `example.com/order/123`.

Now say we want to cancel an order, how are we gonna do it? One may be tempted to think that is a *"cancellation"*  *"action"* and design it as `POST example.com/order/123?do=cancel`.

That is not RESTful, as we talked above. Instead, we might `PUT` a new representation of the `order` with a `canceled` element sent to `true`:

```
PUT /order/123 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml

<order id="123">
    <customer id="89987">...</customer>
    <canceled>true</canceled>
    ...
</order>
```

And that's it. If the order can't be canceled, a specific status code can be returned. <sup>(A subresource design, like `POST /order/123/canceled` with the entity-body `true` may, for simplicity, also be available.)</sup>

In your specific scenario, you may try something similar. That way, while a dog is barking, for example, a `GET` at `/v1/dogs/1/` could include that information <sup>(e.g. `<barking>true</barking>`)</sup>. Or... if that's too complicated, loosen up your RESTful requirement and stick with `POST`.

#### Update:

I don't want to make the answer too big, but it takes a while to get the hang of exposing an algorithm (an *action*) as a set of resources. Instead of thinking in terms of actions (*"do a search for places on the map"*), one needs to think in terms of the results of that action (*"the list of places on the map matching a search
criteria"*).

You may find yourself coming back to this step if you find that your design doesn't fit HTTP's uniform interface.

Query variables **are** *scoping information*, but do **not** denote new resources (`/post?lang=en` is clearly the **same** resource as `/post?lang=jp`, just a different representation). Rather, they are used to convey **client state** (like `?page=10`, so that state is not kept in the server; `?lang=en` is also an example here) or **input parameters** to *algorithmic resources* (`/search?q=dogs`, `/dogs?code=1`). Again, not distinct resources.

### HTTP verbs' (methods) properties:

Another clear point that shows `?action=something` in the URI is not RESTful, are the properties of HTTP verbs:

- `GET` and `HEAD` are safe (and idempotent);
- `PUT` and `DELETE` are idempotent only;
- `POST` is neither.

**Safety**: A `GET` or `HEAD` request is a request to **read** some data, not a request to change any server state. The client can make a `GET` or `HEAD` request 10 times and it's the same as making it once, or *never making it at all*.

**Idempotence**: An idempotent operation in one that has the same effect whether you apply it once or more than once (in math, multiplying by zero is idempotent). If you `DELETE` a resource once, deleting again will have the same effect (the resource is `GONE` already).

<sup><sub>`POST` is neither safe nor idempotent. Making two identical `POST` requests to a 'factory' resource will probably result in two subordinate resources containing the same
information. With overloaded (method in URI or entity-body) `POST`, all bets are off.</sub></sup>

Both these properties were important to the success of the HTTP protocol (over unreliable networks!): how many times have you updated (`GET`) the page without waiting until it is fully loaded?

Creating an *action* and placing it in the URL clearly breaks the HTTP methods' contract. Once again, the technology allows you, you can do it, but that is not RESTful design.

Comment: I take contention with the idea that calling an action on a server, designated as an action in the URL, is not RESTful.

[`POST` was designed for _"providing a block of data...to a data-handling process"_](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). It seems a lot of folks distinguish resources from actions, but really actions are just a type of resource.

Comment: @JacobStevens The OP changed the question a bit so I gotta update my answer to make it more direct (check the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16877968/1), maybe you'll see what I mean). I do agree with `POST` "providing a block of data...to a data-handling process", but the difference is really that, a block of **data**, not a block of data and the procedure (action, method, command) to be executed on then. That is `POST` overloading, and `POST` overloading is RPC-Style design, not RESTful.

Comment: I'm presuming the action/method logic would be housed on the server, else what would the purpose of the call be? In the case you describe, I agree, that wouldn't be good design. But the method or subroutine that performs the action would be specified by the URI (which is another reason why an action resource designated as a verb at the end of a URL is useful and RESTful, though many advise against it).

Comment: No Jacob, the method or subroutine is **not** specified by (any part of) the URI. The *target* of the request is specified by the URI. What to do with the resource is specified as best as possible by the method from those available, and if that is not sufficient, the request body.

Comment: The answer us updated. It is a bit long because a thorough explanation seemed needed ("Keep in mind I have a rudimentary understanding of REST."). It was kind of a struggle to make it as clear complete as possible. Hope it is useful in some way.

Comment: This is a lot of work to do something really simple. Is it worth it to create these abstractions just so you can abide by RESTful principles when you just want to trigger a simple action. What if these actions are not actually owned by anybody or any parent resource? And what happens when you GET barks? Does that mean you always a keep a record of all the barks that happen even when that information is useless?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai we actually discussed several cases, not just the basic one (see the "edit for clarification" part). If the information is useless, don't store it (see case 1.1: the response is just a 200-OK to let the requester know the server understood the request). And, of course, anyone can ditch the principles and implement as s/he wishes and it will work -- considering, of course, that all parts involved are aware of what the URLs and methods mean, that is, what the new "protocol" is.

Comment: The thing about trying to be RESTFul is using the HTTP the way it was best designed to be (the reason it was so successful). One could make it simply a `GET` to `/barks`, but is this really optimal? I take from you comment: is someone performing a `GET` to `/barks` really expecting to issue a new `bark`? Or would they expect to get the info about the barks? In the end, attempting to "be restful" is trying to use HTTP at its best, not just as a transport protocol.

Comment: Great explanation, I voted but the Location header should not be used in 202 Accepted response. It seems to be a wrong interpretation that many people do from RFC. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199228/is-the-use-of-location-header-in-http-202-response-rfc-compliant

Comment: This is a great answear, helped me a lot. I wonder about one thing: sometimes you use `/bark/` and sometimes `/barks/` in URI fragment. Eg. you `POST` on `/v1/dogs/1/barks` but you have `.../dogs/1/bark/a65h44` in Location header in responses. Resource should always be in the plural, right?

Comment: @JarosławKończak yes, the plural is more indicated, I corrected where needed. Thanks

Comment: @Delmo agreed. Although I feel *should not* is too strong. As Roy stated, `Location` could be used with 202, its just that it has no standard behavior for this status code and thus you must make sure the response is understandable using other means, such as the hypertext containing a hyperlink. I added a note to the answer to point that out. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I think 201 is better than 202 when sending the `Location` header. From MDN: "The Location response header indicates the URL to redirect a page to. It only provides a meaning when served with a 3xx (redirection) or 201 (created) status response."

Comment: What's the difference between an "entity-body" and a "document"?

Comment: @maximedupre Kind of. I'd rephrase "It only provides a meaning" to "It is only part of the standard". [As Roy stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26220497/), `Location` could be used with `202`, its just that it has no standard behavior for this status code and thus you must make sure the response is understandable using other means, such as the hypertext containing a hyperlink. In other words: the standard does not tell what `Location` mean for 202, but it does not forbit you to use it for 202. If you use it, you must explain the user what it means. I tried to point that out in the answer...

Comment: I meant "entity-body" and "document" to be synonyms. Do you disagree? (Also the `Location` thing, do you disagree with what I said in the previous comment?)

Comment: It makes sense for the 202/Location use case. Regarding "entity-body" and "document", your phrasing made me think they were two different things (e.g. "entity-body is empty - or, if you require a **document**, place it here"). Personally, I've only ever used the term "request body". I guess I just learned two synonyms :). Cheers!

Comment: @maximedupre Yeah, the "entity-body" is like the "placeholder" for a possible document in the HTTP request/response. In the phrase you mention, maybe "entity-body" would actually be synonym "slot where you place a document". Anyway, I generally use them interchangeably, the context helps to make it clearer. If you'd ask about the term in the specs I'd have to look it up, 'cause I actually don't know off the top of my head for sure.

Comment: Thanks a big lot for this truly great answer, as it is so insightful and comprehensive. I like it a lot and I keep referring back to it occasionally for API designs.

Comment: Hey, @observer, thank you, that means a lot, really!! 

Answer (score 6):

**I [answered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16997574/972499), but this answer contradicts my old answer and follows a much different strategy for coming to a solution.** It shows how the HTTP request is built from the concepts that define REST and HTTP. It also uses `PATCH` instead of `POST` or `PUT`.

It goes through the REST constraints, then the components of HTTP, then a possible solution.

## REST

REST is a set of constraints intended to be applied to a distributed hypermedia system in order to make it scalable. Even to make sense of it in the context of remotely controlling an action, you have to think of remotely controlling an action as a part of a distributed hypermedia system -- a part of a system for discovering, viewing, and modifying interconnected information. If that's more trouble than it's worth, then it's probably no good to try to make it RESTful. If you just want a "control panel" type GUI on the client that can trigger actions on the server via port 80, then you probably want a simple RPC interface like JSON-RPC via HTTP requests/responses or a WebSocket.

But REST is a fascinating way of thinking and the example in the question happens to be easy to model with a RESTful interface, so let's take on the challenge for fun and for education.

REST is [defined](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) by four interface constraints:

> identification of resources; manipulation of resources through representations; self-descriptive messages; and, hypermedia as the engine of application state.

You ask how you can define an interface, meeting these constraints, via which one computer tells another computer to make a dog bark. Specifically, you want your interface to be HTTP, and you don't want to discard the features that make HTTP RESTful when used as intended.

Let's begin with the first constraint: **resource identification**.

> Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on.

So a dog is a resource. It needs to be identified.

> More precisely, a resource *R* is a temporally varying membership function *M<sub>R</sub>*(*t*), which for time *t* maps to a set of entities, or values, which are equivalent. The values in the set may be *resource representations* and/or *resource identifiers*.

You *model* a dog by taking a set of identifiers and representations and saying they are all associated with each other at a given time. For now, let's use the identifier "dog #1". That brings us to the second and third constraints: **resource representation** and **self-description**.

> REST components perform actions on a resource by using a representation to capture the current or intended state of that resource and transferring that representation between components. A representation is a sequence of bytes, plus representation metadata to describe those bytes.

Following is a sequence of bytes capturing the intended state of the dog, i.e. the representation we wish to be associated with the identifier "dog #1" (note that it only represents part of the state as it does not regard the dog's name, health, or even past barks):

> It has been barking every 10 minutes since the time this state change was effected, and will continue indefinitely.

It is supposed to be attached to metadata that describes it. This metadata might be useful:

> It is an English statement. It describes part of the intended state. If it is received multiple times, only allow the first to have an effect.

Finally, let's look at the fourth constraint: **HATEOAS**.

> REST ... views an application as a cohesive structure of information and control alternatives through which a user can perform a desired task. For example, looking-up a word in an on-line dictionary is one application, as is touring through a virtual museum, or reviewing a set of class notes to study for an exam. ... The next control state of an application resides in the representation of the first requested resource, so obtaining that first representation is a priority. ... The model application is therefore an engine that moves from one state to the next by examining and choosing from among the alternative state transitions in the current set of representations.

In a RESTful interface, the client receives a resource representation in order to figure out how it should receive or send a representation. There must be a representation somewhere in the application from which the client can figure out how to receive or send all representations it should be able to receive or send, even if it follows a chain of representations to arrive at that information. This seems simple enough:

The client asks for a representation of a resource identified as the homepage; in response, it gets a representation that contains an identifier of every dog the client might want. The client extracts an identifier from it and asks the service how it can interact with the identified dog, and the service says the client can send an English statement describing part of the intended state of the dog. Then the client sends such a statement and receives a success message or an error message.

## HTTP

HTTP implements REST constraints as follows:

**resource identification**: URI

**resource representation**: entity-body

**self-description**: method or status code, headers, and possibly parts of the entity-body (e.g. the URI of an XML schema)

**HATEOAS**: hyperlinks

You've decided on `http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1` as the URI. Let's assume the client got this from some page on the site.

Let's use this entity-body (the value of `next` is a timestamp; a value of `0` means 'when this request is received'):

```
{"barks": {"next": 0, "frequency": 10}}
```

Now we need a method. [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) fits the "part of the intended state" description we decided on:

> The PATCH method requests that a set of changes described in the request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request-URI.

And some headers:

To indicate the language of the entity-body: `Content-Type: application/json`

To make sure it only happens once: `If-Unmodified-Since: <date/time this was first sent>`

And we have a request:

```
PATCH /v1/dogs/1/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.animals.com
Content-Type: application/json
If-Unmodified-Since: <date/time this was first sent>
[other headers]

{"barks": {"next": 0, "frequency": 10}}
```

On success, the client should receive a [`204`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.5) status code in response, or a `205` if the representation of `/v1/dogs/1/` has changed to reflect the new barking schedule.

On failure, it should receive a `403` and a helpful message why.

It is not essential to REST for the service to reflect the bark schedule in a representation in response to `GET /v1/dogs/1/`, but it would make the most sense if a JSON representation included this:

```
"barks": {
    "previous": [x_1, x_2, ..., x_n],
    "next": x_n,
    "frequency": 10
}
```

Treat the cron job as an implementation detail that the server hides from the interface. That's the beauty of a generic interface. The client doesn't have to know what the server does behind the scenes; all it cares about is that the service understands and responds to requested state changes.

Answer (score 4):

Most people use *POST* for this purpose.  It is appropriate for performing "any unsafe or nonidempotent operation when no other HTTP method seems appropriate".

APIs such as [XMLRPC](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html) use *POST* to trigger actions that can run arbitrary code.  The "action" is included in the POST data:

```
POST /RPC2 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Frontier/5.1.2 (WinNT)
Host: betty.userland.com
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-length: 181

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>examples.getStateName</methodName>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value><i4>41</i4></value>
         </param>
      </params>
   </methodCall>
```

The RPC is example is given to show that POST is the conventional choice of HTTP verbs for server-side methods.  Here's [Roy Fielding thoughts on POST](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post) -- he pretty much says it is RESTful to use the HTTP methods as specified.

Note that RPC itself isn't very RESTful because it isn't resource oriented.  But if you need statelessness, caching, or layering, it's not hard to make the appropriate transformations.  See http://blog.perfectapi.com/2012/opinionated-rpc-apis-vs-restful-apis/ for an example.

Comment: I think you would URLencode the params not put it in the query string

Comment: @Kirk Yes, but with one minor modification, drop the final forward slash:  ``POST api.animals.com/v1/dogs1?action=bark``

Comment: if you follow the advice in this answer, bear in mind that the resulting API will not be RESTful.

Comment: This isn't RESTful **because** HTTP establishes the URL as the identifier of a resource and a URL of `/RPC2` does nothing to identify a resource -- it identifies a server technology. Instead, this uses `methodName` to try to 'identify' the 'resource' -- but even then, it doesn't benefit from the noun/verb distinction; the only 'verb'-like thing here is `methodCall`. This is like 'do state-name-retrieval' instead of 'retrieve state-name' -- the latter makes so much more sense.

Comment: +1 for the links; very informative and the "opinionated RPC" experiment is inventive.

Answer (score 2):

`POST` is the [HTTP method designed](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) for

> *Providing a block of data...to a data-handling process*

Server-side methods handling non-CRUD-mapped actions is what [Roy Fielding intended](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~taylor/documents/2002-REST-TOIT.pdf) with REST, so you're good there, and that's why `POST` was made to be non-idempotent. `POST` will handle most posting of data to server-side methods to process the information.

That said, in your dog-barking scenario, if you want a server-side bark to be performed every 10 minutes, but for some reason need the trigger to originate from a client, `PUT` would serve the purpose better, because of its idempotence. Well, strictly by this scenario there's no apparent risk of multiple POST requests causing your dog to meow instead, but anyway that's the purpose of the two similar methods. [My answer to a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717819/what-restful-http-request-for-executing-actions-on-the-server/16721577#16721577) may be useful for you.

Comment: PUT vs. POST is all about the URL. The third paragraph after [9.6 PUT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) says the purpose of the two methods is so the `PUT` URL refers to what should be **replaced** by the client's content and the `POST` URL refers to what should **process** the client's content however it wants.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier revisions of some answers suggested you use RPC. You do not need to look to RPC as it *is* perfectly possible to do what you want whilst adhering to the REST constraints.

Firstly, don't put action parameters in the URL. The URL defines *what* you are applying the action to, and query parameters are part of the URL. It should be thought of entirely as a **noun.** `http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/?action=bark` is a different resource — a different noun — to `http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/`. [n.b. Asker has removed the `?action=bark` URI from the question.] For example, compare `http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/?id=1` to `http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/?id=2`. Different resources, distinguished only by query string. So the action of your request, unless it corresponds directly to a bodyless existing method type (TRACE, OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, DELETE, etc) must be defined in the request body.

Next, decide if the action is "[idempotent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1)", meaning that it can be repeated without adverse effect (see next paragraph for more explanaton). For example, setting a value to true can be repeated if the client is unsure that the desired effect happened. They send the request again and the value remains true. Adding 1 to a number is not idempotent. If the client sends the Add1 command, isn't sure it worked, and sends it again, did the server add one or two? Once you have determined that, you're in a better position to choose between `PUT` and `POST` for your method.

Idempotent means a request can be *repeated without changing the outcome.* These effects do not include logging and other such server admin activity. Using your first and second examples, sending two emails to the same person does result in a different state than sending one email (the recipient has two in their inbox, which they might consider to be spam), so I would definitely use POST for that. If the barkCount in example 2 is intended to be seen by a user of your API or affects something that is client-visible, then it is also something that would make the request non-idempotent. If it is only to be viewed by you then it counts as server logging and should be ignored when determing idempotentcy.

Lastly, determine if the action you want to perform can be expected to succeed immediately or not. BarkDog is a quickly completing action. RunMarathon is not. If your action is slow, consider returning a `202 Accepted`, with a URL in the response body for a user to poll to see if the action is complete. Alternatively, have users POST to a list URL like `/marathons-in-progress/` and then when the action is done, redirect them from the in progress ID URL to the `/marathons-complete/` URL.
For the specific cases #1 and #2, I would have the server host a queue, and the client post batches of addresses to it. The action would not be SendEmails, but something like AddToDispatchQueue. The server can then poll the queue to see if there are any email addresses waiting, and send emails if it finds any. It then updates the queue to indicate that the pending action has now been performed. You would have another URI showing the client the current state of the queue. To avoid double-sending of emails, the server could also keep a log of who it has sent this email to, and check each address against that to ensure it never sends two to the same address, even if you POST the same list twice to the queue.

When choosing a URI for anything, try to think of it as a result, not an action. For example `google.com/search?q=dogs` shows the **results** of a search for the word "dogs". It does not necessarilly perform the search.

Cases #3 and #4 from your list are also not idempotent actions. You suggest that the different suggested effects might affect the API design. In all four cases I would use the same API, as all four change the “world state.”

Comment: Let's say the action is to churn through a giant email queue and send a message to a bunch of people. Is that idempotent? Are idempotent actions for PUT or POST?

Comment: @kirk I have expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume Barking is an inner / dependent / sub resource which the consumer can act on, then we could say:

```
POST http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/bark
```

dog number 1 barks

```
GET http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/bark
```

returns the last bark timestamp

```
DELETE http://api.animals.com/v1/dogs/1/bark
```

doesn't apply! so ignore it.

Comment: This is only RESTful if you consider `/v1/dogs/1/bark` to be a resource _per se_, and `POST` to be a description of how that resource's internal state should change. I find that it makes more sense just to consider `/v1/dogs/1/` as a resource and to indicate in the entity-body that it should bark.

Comment: mmm.. well, it's a resource which you can change its state. Because the result of changing its state is making noise, doesn't make it less resource! You are looking at Bark as a verb (which is) that's why you can't consider it a resource. I'm looking at it as a dependent resource which its state can be changed and since its state is boolean, I don't see any reason to mention it in entity-body. That's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**See my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17016682/972499)** -- it contradicts this one and explains REST and HTTP more clearly and accurately.

Here's a **recommendation** that happens to be RESTful but is certainly not the only option. To start barking when the service receives the request:

```
POST /v1/dogs/1/bark-schedule HTTP/1.1
...
{"token": 12345, "next": 0, "frequency": 10}
```

`token` is an arbitrary number that prevents redundant barks no matter how many times this request is sent.

`next` indicates the time of the next bark; a value of `0` means 'ASAP'.

Whenever you `GET /v1/dogs/1/bark-schedule`, you should get something like this, where *t* is the time of the last bark and *u* is *t* + 10 minutes:

`{"last": t, "next": u}`

I highly recommend that you use the same URL to request a bark that you use to find out about the dog's current barking state. It's not essential to REST, but it emphasizes the act of modifying the schedule.

The appropriate status code is probably [205](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.6). I'm imagining a client that looks at the current schedule, `POST`s to the same URL to change it, and is instructed by the service to give the schedule a second look to prove that it has been changed.

## Explanation

### REST

[image]

Forget about HTTP for a moment. It's essential to understand that a [resource](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) is a function that takes time as input and returns a set containing *identifiers* and *representations*. Let's simplify that to: a resource is a set *R* of identifiers and representations; *R* can change -- members can be added, removed, or modified. (Though it's bad, unstable design to remove or modify identifiers.) We say an identifier that is an element of *R* identifies *R*, and that a representation that is an element of *R* represents *R*.

Let's say *R* is a dog. You happen to identify *R* as `/v1/dogs/1`. (Meaning `/v1/dogs/1` is a member of *R*.) That's just one of many ways you could identify *R*. You could also identify *R* as `/v1/dogs/1/x-rays` and as `/v1/rufus`.

How do you represent *R*? Maybe with a photograph. Maybe with a set of X-rays. Or maybe with an indication of the date and time when *R* last barked. But remember that these are all representations of *the same resource*. `/v1/dogs/1/x-rays` is an identifier of the same resource that is represented by an answer to the question "when did *R* last bark?"

### HTTP

[image]

Multiple representations of a resource aren't very useful if you can't refer to the one you want. That's why HTTP is useful: it lets you [connect identifiers to representations](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2_2). That is, it is a way for the service to receive a URL and decide which representation to serve to the client.

At least, that's what `GET` does. `PUT` is basically the inverse of `GET`: you `PUT` a representation *r* at the URL if you wish for future `GET` requests to that URL to return *r*, with some possible translations like JSON to HTML.

`POST` is a looser way of modifying a representation. Think of there being display logic and modification logic that are counterparts to each other -- both corresponding to the same URL. A POST request is a request for the modification logic to process the information and modify any representations (not just the representation located by the same URL) as the service sees fit. Pay attention to the third paragraph after [9.6 PUT](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6): you're not replacing the thing at the URL with new content; you're asking the thing at the URL to process some information and intelligently respond in the form of informative representations.

In our case, we ask the modification logic at `/v1/dogs/1/bark-schedule` (which is the counterpart to the display logic that tells us when it last barked and when it will next bark) to process our information and modify some representations accordingly. In response to future `GET`s, the display logic corresponding to the same URL will tell us that the dog is now barking as we wish.

Think of the cron job as an implementation detail. HTTP deals in viewing and modifying representations. From now on, the service will tell the client when the dog last barked and when it will bark next. From the service's perspective, that is honest because those times correspond with past and planned cron jobs.

Answer (score -1):

REST is a resource oriented standard, it is not action driven as a RPC would be.

If you want your server to *bark*, you should look into different ideas like [JSON-RPC](http://json-rpc.org/), or into websockets communication.

Every try to keep it RESTful will fail in my opinion: you can issue a `POST` with the `action` parameter, you are not creating any new resources but as you may have side effects, you are safer.

Comment: [`POST` was designed for _"providing a block of data...to a data-handling process"_](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). It seems a lot of folks distinguish resources from actions, but really actions are just a type of resource.

Calling an action resource on a server is still a uniform interface, cacheable, modular and scalable. 

It's also stateless, but that can be violated if the client is designed to expect a response. But calling a "void method" on the server is what [Roy Fielding intended with REST](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~taylor/documents/2002-REST-TOIT.pdf).

Comment: As I describe in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16997574/972499), you can in REST implicitly cause the server to perform an action by asking it to say, from now on, "your action was completed", whereas RPC is based on the idea of just asking the server to perform the action. Both make perfect sense, just as imperative and declarative programming both make sense.