# How do I make arbitrary API calls using Ember.js?

Tags: rest, ember.js

What I'm trying to do is described in great detail here:

[Call a Server-side Method on a Resource in a RESTful Way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877968/call-a-server-side-method-on-a-resource-in-a-restful-way)

I have Ember Data's RESTAdapter working with my API, but now I want to give Ember.js a way to kick off various server-side actions using custom routes, such as `/docs/1/share` or `/docs/1/activate`.  The former would possibly modify the record but the latter would not.

What's the best way to do this?

TIA!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ember has jQuery baked in.  In your controller:

```
actions: {
    activate: function() {
        var docId= this.get('id'), self= this;
        Ember.$.ajax({
            url: '/docs/%@/activate'.fmt(docId),
            // your other details...
        }).then(function(resolve) {
            self.set('name', resolve.doc.name);
            // process the result...
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if I were to want to update the current model with whatever object `resolve` contains, I would just do a `this.set('name', resolve.doc.name);` for every field I want to replace?

Comment: The `resolve` variable will contain whatever the server responds with in this ajax() call.  You cannot use `this`, since it refers to a different object than the controller.  Keep a reference to the controller via a closure.  I will update the answer to illustrate...

Comment: JQuery is going to be removed from Ember.js so this answer is probably outdated

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `ic-ajax` which is a nice wrapper around `jQuery.ajax`, you can see an example here [using ix-ajax](https://github.com/abuiles/borrowers/commit/541f1448585b7b720746c8a0ddb3aa5c2bc9ad67#diff-6a1ed880db04cd9247e691c3582eb254R1).