# REST vs Session-Based-Applications

Tags: web-services, rest

I got a question regarding REST vs other web services, but I just can't figure out where to start. I know what REST ist and how services implemented with it should work, I also have a basic understanding of SOAP and RPCs, but I really can't tell what is meant with the question what differs REST from session-based-applications.

I know that REST is stateless, but how can I answer this question correctly? Any hints or good sources to read through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What differs REST from session-based apps?

REST is different fron session-based applications because it is stateless and session-based are not.

Keeping "Session" is nothing more than the server keeping the state of the user.

REST doesn't do that, it uses hypermedia to guide the state of the app. That's where the HATEOAS acronym comes from (**H**ypermedia **A**s **T**he **E**ngine **O**f **A**pplication **S**tate).

Basically, HATEOAS means your service should guide its clients the same way a regular website guides its users: by means of hyperlinks (and media types). [Roy Fielding expands on this in his blog.](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)