# Which HTTP method to use?

Tags: java, web-services

I am developing a RESTful web service in Java which on clients requests receives a request body which contains a set of computation tasks. The service(server) does the task and returns the output of the task to the client. I am having a problem on which HTTP method to use for the request - POST or PUT? I have read that POST is used for creating a resource and PUT is used for creating/updating a resource. But here I am doing neither an updating nor creating. But still I want my request body to contain the set of tasks for the server to do. So which **HTTP** method should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you invoke the REST service needs to accept a JSON. Suitable methods to send json as a part of body is POST and PUT, that are documented for create/update request.

Long answer short, use either POST or PUT which are suitable to post JSON and send back reply.

Comment: is it necessary to create a resource to use PUT or POST?

Comment: The REST specifications are based on CRUD operation on a database table, parameter of json are parallels to columns. It doesn't limit us to write custom logic at the server side. Hence you can leverage POST/PUT which accepts json doc through body as input to your server side operation. Accepting json document as part of request is not possible in other request types like GET.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to create a **new** resourse on your server then you should to use **POST** method. Your task for server - is resourse which you'll create by request. So, use POST.

Comment: but I am not creating any resource? Thats why I wanted to know which method to use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question [Call a Server-side Method on a Resource in a RESTful Way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877968/call-a-server-side-method-on-a-resource-in-a-restful-way) could help to understand how to use server-side method calls with a rest api in addition to Maksim Grakov's answer