# Call server-side function from ReactJS component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement a payments system in my ReactJS app that requires server-side code.

I have several questions:

- How do you connect a ReactJS app so it can communicate with server-side code?
- How would you set up a function in the server-side code?
- How would you call that function from a component in a ReactJS app?

For reference, I'm trying to integrate [Stripe subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart). They give server-side code examples for Node, PHP, etc.

FYI: I am not trying to set up server-side rendering. When you search for server-side code in reference to ReactJS, that's just about all that comes up.

EDIT: I'm particularly interested in a NodeJS solution. I'm also using Webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case, it is helpful to you... I have a React UI that triggers video processing on a Django backend (I mainly use GraphQL through Apollo Client to trigger my server side functions and REST framework when file transfers are involved).
[Is REST an option for you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877968/call-a-server-side-method-on-a-resource-in-a-restful-way)

The middleware I use for file transfers for example:

```
const SERVER_URL = process.env.SERVER_URL;

const fileTransferApi = (payload) => {
  const { authenticated, token, endpoint, body, contentType, method } = payload;

  let config = {};

  if (authenticated) {
    if (token) {
      config = {
        method,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': contentType,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body
      };
    } else {
      throw new Error('No token saved!');
    }
  }

  return fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/api/rest/v1/${endpoint}`, config)
    .then((response) =>
      response.text().then((text) => ({ text, response }))
    ).then(({ text, response }) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(text);
      }
      return text;
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
};


export const FILE_TRANSFER_API = Symbol('FILE_TRANSFER_API');

export default () => (next) => (action) => {
  const fileTransferApiAction = action[FILE_TRANSFER_API];

  if (typeof fileTransferApiAction === 'undefined') {
    return next(action);
  }

  const { payload, types } = fileTransferApiAction;

  const [, successType, errorType] = types;

  return fileTransferApi(payload).then(
    (response) =>
      next({
        type: successType,
        payload: {
          text: response,
          message: 'ok'
        }
      }),
    (error) => next({
      type: errorType,
      payload: {
        error: error.message || 'There was an error.'
      }
    })
  );
};
```

My store (I use Redux):

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import ApolloClientSingleton from '../network/apollo-client-singleton';
import fileTransferApi from '../middlewares/fileTransferApi';

import reducer from './reducers';

export default class Store {
  constructor(history, initialState = {}) {
    this.data = createStore(
      reducer,
      initialState,
      compose(
        applyMiddleware(
          fileTransferApi,
          ReduxThunk.withExtraArgument(ApolloClientSingleton),
          routerMiddleware(history),
          ApolloClientSingleton.middleware()
        ),
        typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.devToolsExtension !== 'undefined'
          ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => f
      )
    );
  }
}
```

In my actions:

```
export const windowsDownload = (authenticated, token) => ({
  [FILE_TRANSFER_API]: {
    types: [WINDOW_DOWNLOAD_REQUEST, WINDOW_DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS, WINDOW_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE],
    payload: {
      endpoint: 'file_transfer/download/windows',
      contentType: 'text/csv',
      method: 'get',
      body: null,
      authenticated,
      token
    }
  }
});
```

This REST setup enables me to send requests (POST video, GET csv...) from my React UI to my Django server. **Can't you set up some REST calls between your app and your server?**

Comment: I'm working on an implementation similar to your answer -- I don't nearly have all the kinks worked out yet, but I think it's safe to call your answer the correct one. A REST solution seems to be the way to go. The piece I've been missing all along is the server piece. I've just got to get the server set up so I can make calls to it, and then your solution should work just fine. Thanks!