# Send information to server using POST call instead of using curl

Tags: curl, post

I am supposed to send information to server using curl but my embedded device doesn't support libcurl library yet. As I googled it out, it looks like I can use POST and get things done but am getting error 400 from server when I do the same. All I had to do with Curl was that to add HTTP header and then post data and it goes like

URL shared:

```
https://api.sampledomain.com/v1/action
```

Header:

```
Authorization: Bearer aabbccddee
```

Data:

```
{"action":"112233445566","device_id":"1234567890"}
```

Below is the POST command I compiled and the string goes like below.

```
POST /v1/action HTTP/1.1
Host: api.sampledomain.com
Authorization: Bearer aabbccddee
{"action":"112233445566","device_id":"1234567890"}
```

Response for the above POST command was: 400

Please help me out guys. Thanks.

Comment: I used the below link to confirm that it's possible to use POST instead of relying on curl. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877968/call-a-server-side-method-on-a-resource-in-a-restful-way

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error. I had to give two spaces below the data section after the curly braces. It worked like a charm.

```
POST /v1/action HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 105
Host: api-sampledomain.com
Authorization: Bearer aabbccddee

{"action":"112233445566","device_id":"12345678"}
```